# Rendering a List<Map<String, Object>> in an LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json, map, list

I already posted a question about this, but I'm asking it again, differently. I'm importing a getFiltersJson apex method to my component (what it does, is export some filters I created in another method in that class called getFilters):

```
public static QueryFilters getFilters(){
    QueryFilters filters = new QueryFilters();

    filters.add(new QueryFilters.StringFilter(new QueryFilters.Field(Account.Name)));
    filters.add(new QueryFilters.InFilter(new QueryFilters.FieldOptions(Account.sobjectType, Account.Industry)));
    filters.add(new QueryFilters.NumberFilter(new QueryFilters.Field(Account.NumberOfEmployees, 'Empleados desde'), QueryFilters.Operator.GE));
    filters.add(new QueryFilters.NumberFilter(new QueryFilters.Field(Account.NumberOfEmployees, 'Empleados hasta'), QueryFilters.Operator.LE));
    filters.add(new QueryFilters.FilterWithOperators(new QueryFilters.NumberFilter(new QueryFilters.Field(Account.NumberofLocations__c))));
    filters.add(new QueryFilters.BooleanFilter(new QueryFilters.Field(Account.Tested__c)).selectize());
            
    return filters;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Map<String, Object>> getFiltersJson(){
    return QueryFilters.export((List<QueryFilters.ExportableFilter>)getFilters().filters);
}
```

As you see, this method returns a List<Map<String, Object>>. I received some answers saying this in javascript translates to an array of objects, but I tried asigning the data received to a property in my lwc controller and I get an undefined error in the iteration. In this code I receive the data, and assign it:

```
@api filters;

@wire(getFiltersJson)
loadFilters({ error, data }){
    if(data){
        console.log(data);
        this.filters = data;
    }else if(error){
        //do something
    }
    
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<template class="iterador" iterator:it={filters}>
        <c-lwc-filter
            filter={it}
            key={it.value.label}>
        </c-lwc-filter>
    </template>
```

When I try to run it, to see if it renders, the console throws an error, like 'filters' is undefined. Do I have to create an array in my js work through the data received in the apex method? Do i need something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @joacoiudica, I answered your previous post. In this case, the issue is likely that your iterator template is trying to run _before your wired method completes_. At that point in time, `filters` will be `undefined` because it has not been defined as anything yet. You can either assign filters to be an empty array by default (`filters = []`) or force the template to only render once `filters` is defined.

Can you share what `console.log(data)` outputs?

Comment: I nested the iterator template inside a template if:true{filters}, and now the undefined problem is gone. But, I have another error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) at :3333/webruntime/api/apex/execute:1

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with my apex method?

Comment: the console log doesn't output anything, so maybe there is no data.

Comment: Most HTTP 500 errors point to a problem on the server. Your Apex method likely has issues. Are the properties on the `QueryFilters` class `AuraEnabled` and serializable? Some object types cannot be sent client-side from the server.

Comment: In the getFiltersJson, I pass as a parameter to the export method, the filters property of the instance of queryFilters in the getFilters method. the filters property is a list<Filter>, so maybe I have to make that auraenabled?

Comment: Test your Apex code in Execute Anonymous. Do you get back what you expect? If so, then the problem is some part of the return values is not AuraEnabled or not possible to be returned to the client-side.